# Stability concerns SAP BO 4.0

Tags: business-objects

I am evaluating SAP BO 4.0 for our BI implementation. I have been exploring SAP BO web intelligence. Once of my concern is when creating reports, it often breaks. And the new functionality of bringing in data from Excel spreadsheets and merging with existing universe doesn't work as expected.

Have any of you encountered the same kind of problems?

Any insights from people who have worked and deployed the latest version could be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have had the same issues.  Reports that would breeze through XI 3.1 have been a nightmare to create in SAP BI 4.

The product only approaches being stable on SP4.  Do not implement SP5 we have had further serious problems in the security model with this version.

SAP really need to seriously start concentrating on stability of the software if they are to retain their existing customer base.